# Error unrecognized argument --hive-partition-key

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

I am getting error `Unrecognized argument --hive-partition-key` , when I run the following statement:

```
sqoop import 
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.56.1;database=xyz_dms_cust_100;username-hadoop;password=hadoop' 
--table e_purchase_category 
--hive_import 
--delete-target-dir 
--hive-table purchase_category_p 
--hive-partition-key "creation_date" 
--hive-partition-value "2015-02-02"
```

The partitioned table exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hive partition key (`creation_date` in your example) should not be part of your database table when you are using `hive-import`. When you are trying to create table in hive with partition you will not include partition column in your table schema. The same applies to sqoop `hive-import` as well.

Based on your sqoop command, i am guessing that `creation_date` column is present in your SQLServer table. If yes, you might be getting this error

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: 
Partition key creation_date cannot be a column to import.
```

To resolve this issue, i have two solutions:

1. Make sure that the partition column is not present in the SQLServer table. So, when sqoop creates hive table it includes that partition column and its value as directory in hive warehouse.
2. Change the sqoop command by including a **free form query** to get all the columns expect the partiton column and do hive-import. Below is a example for this solution

**Example:**

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexamples 
--query 'select City.ID, City.Name, City.District, City.Population from City where $CONDITIONS' 
--target-dir /user/XXXX/City
--delete-target-dir 
--hive-import 
--hive-table City
--hive-partition-key "CountryCode" 
--hive-partition-value "USA" 
--fields-terminated-by ',' 
-m 1
```

**Another method:**
You can also try to do your tasks in different steps:

1. Create a partition table in hive (Example: city_partition)
2. Load data from RDBMS to sqoop using hive-import into a plain hive table (Example: city)
3. Using insert overwrite, import data into partition table (city_partition) from plain hive table (city) like:

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE city_partition
PARTITION (CountryCode='USA')
SELECT id, name, district, population FROM city;`

Answer (score 0):

## It could applied too :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/akash
--username root
--P
--table mytest
--where "dob='2019-12-28'"
--columns "id,name,salary"
--target-dir /user/cloudera/
--m 1 --hive-table mytest
--hive-import
--hive-overwrite
--hive-partition-key dob
--hive-partition-value '2019-12-28'
```